# asp:LinkButton vs asp:Button. Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently use asp:LinkButton instead of asp:Button for some CSS styles.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegister" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnSend" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_Click">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

I wonder that when I click on `btnRegister_Click` I get error that

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

but there is no error on `Button1_Click`.

I know that disabling `EnableEventValidation="false"` has some security issues.

1. What's different between asp:LinkButton and asp:Button on postback event?
2. what is best and secure solution in this case?

**Edit:**
There is no code on load and click, I was confused with my designer coding :)).
I realize that there are multi forms without `runat=server` but with `method=postback` attributes. I clear that extra forms and problem resolved.

any Idea of why `asp:linkbutton` behavior like this neither `asp:button`?

**Edit 2:** please don't tell me to change `EnableEventValidation` to false, I don't want the risk of page security. also, I add

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

in web.config and didn't work.

Comment: We need more information, can you show delegate for `btnRegister_Click` and some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

if you bind gridview or datalist or repeater in page load, must do it:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        //all code in page_load
        }
     }
```

already You could do as the error message suggests and use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Or you could just set EnableEventValidation for the page to false.

Comment: no there is no binding. I just want to send postback using asp:linkbutton

Answer (score -1):

Check with `AutoEventWireup="true"`

Comment: Please provide some explanation why this answers the question.